# Confused about nginx proxy and sni

Tags: nginx, sni, resin

## Server info

I have a server with nginx 1.12.1 enabled sni and resin 3.1.6 on jdk 1.6.0

The nginx here use 80 port to proxy 8080 and 443 port to proxy 8443 of resin.

## First issue

When the nginx is running, I can get access with 80. But access to 443, I will get a 502 error, and in the error log, I got `dh key too small`.

## Second issue

Then I compile the nginx with openssl-0.9.8f,and sni is disabled.This time I got everything to be done.But when I compile the nginx with openssl-0.9.8f and enable the sni.I got a 502 again,and error log is `SSL: error:1
40773F2:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert unexpected message`

## What I confused

So,the first issue about `dh key too small` is belong to `Weak Diffie-Hellman` ? The reason is my jdk is too old?

And the second issue is because nginx send sni information to resin,but resin doesn't support sni,so can't do ssl handshake?